# PHP Error: Undefined index: event_list when I think its already defined.

Tags: php

I am a complete noob in PHP and programming as well. I am very new to programming so my question might look stupid, but please be patient.

I am having an undefined index error in which I think its already defined.

I have here the codes.

**`index.php`**

```
<?php include('functions.php'); ?>

<?php 
 $yr = $_GET['year_list'];
 $evnt = $_GET['event_list']; 
?>

<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <form name="myform" >
   Select Year: <?php echo hspacer(1); ?>
   <select id="year_list" name="year_list">
   <?php  
    for($year = (date('Y') - 100); $year <= (date('Y') + 100); $year++ ) {
     if ($year == date('Y'))  echo "<option value='$year' name='$year' selected='' >" . $year . "</option>";
     else echo "<option value='$year' name='$year' >" . $year . "</option>";
    }
   ?>
   </select>
   <?php echo hspacer(5); ?>
   Select Event:  <?php echo hspacer(1); ?>
   <select id="event_list" name="event_list" >
   <?php  
    $events = array("Karate Tournament", "Beauty Pageant", "Film Festival", "Singing Contest", "Wedding");

    foreach($events as $event) echo "<option value='$event' name='$event' >" . $event . "</option>";
   ?>
   </select>
   <?php echo vspacer(2); echo hspacer(22); ?>
   <input type="submit" id="add_description" name="add_description" value="Add Description" onclick=""/> 
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`functions.php`**

```
<?php
 function hspacer($num_of_spaces) {
  $spaces = "";
  if ($num_of_spaces > 0)  for($i=0; $i<$num_of_spaces; $i++ )  $spaces .= "&nbsp;";

  return $spaces;
 }

 function vspacer($num_of_linefeeds) {
  $linefeeds = "";
  if ($num_of_linefeeds > 0)  for($i=0; $i<$num_of_linefeeds; $i++ )  $linefeeds .= "<br />";

  return $linefeeds;
 }
?>
```

What I don't understand about this, is that I think when you declared an element with an ID you can use the ID as index for `$_GET` or `$_POST`. Secondly, why is it that the second element (`event_list`) is not recognized when they have the same declaration as the first element which is (`year_list`).  I'm confused with the inconsistency. Only the second element is not recognized while the other first one is recognized. Can somebody please explain to me in a simple way that a beginner like me can understand.

Comment: use `print_r($_GET)` and `print_r($_REQUEST)`, and let me know what is it printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you have `&year_list` allready in your url, when accessing that page? For otherwise there would be no reason to not get the same error when accessing `$_GET['year_list'];`

And generally you should check your access to _GET/_POST etc. instead of just assuming the keys are set.

Try:

```
$yr = isset($_GET['year_list']) ? $_GET['year_list'] : null;
$evnt = isset($_GET['event_list']) ? $_GET['event_list'] : null;
```

You could also build a function to reduce some of the code. Also have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php and
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals